# Feeding an array of scores into Python sklearn cross_val_score during multi-class classification

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am classifying a multi-classed target:

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2] 
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
X = pd.DataFrame([0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1])
model = LogisticRegression()
this_works = precision_score(y, y_pred, average=None)
print(this_works)
this_doesnt_work = cross_val_score(model, X, y, 
    scoring = make_scorer(precision_score, average=None))
```

The error message is:

```
[ 0.66666667  0.          0.        ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-264248a211de> in <module>()
      6 print(this_works)
      7 this_doesnt_work = cross_val_score(model, X, y, 
----> 8     scoring = make_scorer(precision_score, average=None))

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    138                                               train, test, verbose, None,
    139                                               fit_params)
--> 140                       for train, test in cv_iter)
    141     return np.array(scores)[:, 0]
    142 

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    606                 return False
    607             else:
--> 608                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    609                 return True
    610 

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    569         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    570         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 571         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    572         self._jobs.append(job)
    573 

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    107     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    108         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 109         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    110         if callback:
    111             callback(result)

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    324         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    325         # arguments in memory
--> 326         self.results = batch()
    327 
    328     def get(self):

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    258     else:
    259         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 260         test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    261         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    262         if return_train_score:

/Users/katharina/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    296     if not isinstance(score, numbers.Number):
    297         raise ValueError("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) instead."
--> 298                          % (str(score), type(score)))
    299     return score
    300 

ValueError: scoring must return a number, got [ 0.66666667  1.          1.        ] (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) instead.
```

Is there a way to use `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` in conjunction with a `scorer` that returns not just a scalar but an array?

I am mostly interested in whether cross_val_score and the scorer have the capability of doing what I am asking. I had already gotten what I needed with some workaround as posted below for your reference; I am also aware that there is a `average` parameter within `precision_score` which can return an average score. Thanks.

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2] 
#y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
X = pd.DataFrame([0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1])
model = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
#this_works = precision_score(y, y_pred, average=None)
#print(this_works)
#this_doesnt_work = cross_val_score(model, X, y, 
#    scoring = make_scorer(precision_score, average=None))

y = label_binarize(y, classes = [0, 1, 2])
for i in range(3):
    myscore = cross_val_score(model, X, y[:, i], 
        scoring = make_scorer(precision_score))
    print(i, myscore)
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? Are you getting any errors? Then please post them here.

Comment: @VivekKumar I have added the error message. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No, the cross_val_score only handles single number as scores. You can either try changing the `average` to 'micro' or 'macro', or maybe try implementing custom version of cross_val_score to handle those in single cross-validation only. How do you want your output?

Comment: Thanks, you've answered my question. I was hoping for `cross_val_score` to output a 2D array - one dimension for each fold; one for multiple scoring. Like I said, I am aware of the `average` parameter, which isn't what I wanted.